# Which cast style is better and why?

Tags: c++, constants, readability, maintainability

Imagine in C++ two classes one named `derived` and another named `base` that is a base class of the first.  If I had the following code, which is preferred:

```
base *b = init_value_here;
const derived *d = static_cast<derived *>(b);
```

or

```
base *b = init_value_here;
const derived *d = static_cast<const derived *>(b);
```

In other words, is it better to exclude `const` in the static cast when not required since the compiler can promote to constness, or is it better to include it to loosen the restrictions on `b` such that it could be made `const` in the future more readily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strive to do the least number of explicit casts possible, and everything else implicit, if possible.

So I would use the former (i.e not including `const` in the cast).

But this is only my opinion. You may be of the opinion to write the `const` there too, as it fits your taste.

Answer (score 8):

Neither one if possible. Design your class so that the base class defines a fully useful interface and use only the base class pointer.

Sometimes however you're stuck with legacy code, in which case I would explicitly spell out that you're casting it to const.

EDIT: I should make it clear that there are occasionally cases where a non-polymorphic situation arises and a solution using a cast would be appropriate. Generally speaking downcasting may be a design smell but it doesn't always indicate that something is definitely wrong.

Comment: +1 for reminding the OP that this sort of scenario should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: +1 for the right answer. -1 for implying that polymorphism should always be employed... which is of course simply not true.

Answer (score 3):

Well, to be clear, they do the same thing.

Now, if you were converting from a `const base *` to a `const derived *`, only the latter would be valid, and the former would require a `const_cast` as well. If you were converting from a `base *` to a `derived *`, only the former would be valid, since otherwise you'd need to cast away the `const`-ness that your cast just added.

My preference would be to avoid using `const` modifiers in a cast unless explicitly needed. Keep the code as simple as the compiler allows, in other words.

Of course, you should be using `dynamic_cast<>` rather than `static_cast<>` in this scenario, if `b` could be an instance of another derived class.

Comment: Do remember that `dynamic_cast` *does* require the classes to be polymorphic.

Comment: Replace "since" with "if" in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

For just a line of code I wouldn't worry about it much. If you do change `b` to `const base*` in future then the compiler will tell you exactly what line is problematic and what to change. So the benefits are pretty minimal either way - one of them makes the line shorter, the other one *might* save you a few seconds' work in future on an occasion when you're already in that same function changing the code. I'd put the `const` in if it occurred to me to do so, since it slightly reduces the reliance of one line of code on the details of another line. But I wouldn't go out of my way to change it if the code was already written.

If you're designing an API, then you'd put `const` where you can, because changing an API might be painful. I don't think this potential future change is painful.